# Multiple Graphics cards - need to be the same?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I'm about to build a new PC, and I'm looking at Graphics Cards. I want a good one for Gaming, so I'm either looking at the 1796 MB GeForce GTX 260 or I'll get something cheap and wait for the Fermi cards, whatever.

But I want to connect multiple Monitors - at least 3, possibly 4. I just wonder if I can take another graphic card model for that? I don"t want SLi, but I guess I should take another nVidia at least?

Is there any Problem when mixing graphic cards that way? I know it works fine for Office Applications (I believe that the [iMo Pivot](http://www.mimomonitors.com/products/iMo) contains a USB Graphic Card), but I don't know if there are any issues with gaming?

Operating System is Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any combination of AGP, PCI-X, or PCI 2.0 video cards will give you the multiple monitor goodness you desire.  However, if they aren't all using the same driver, or if they aren't WDDM Compliant (which all recent cards are), you won't be able to use Aero Glass.

Therefore you probably want a "[Heterogeneous Multi-Adapter](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/display/multimonVista.mspx) Configuration".

Comment: Thanks for that link, that should help. Now it's still up to me to decide which card to get right now...

Answer (score 1):

Many of our system have mixed graphic adapters. Without any problem. Often we have Intel on Board an install in addition a Nvidia Gforce for graphical applications.

Comment: Do you use them for Gaming as well?

Comment: No, but our customers are often architects working with CAD. The load should equal to ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the 5800-series of ATI since these cards support multiple screens and offer a better price-quality ratio than any card of nVidia at the moment.

Furthermore, I recommend you have a look at [my answer in another question about heterogeneous videocards](https://superuser.com/questions/15726/two-different-nvidia-cards-one-as-graphics-one-as-physics-possible/15736#15736)

Comment: I second that. Some of the newer cards have four or even six displayports, all on one card... that should be plenty!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, I didn't realize that the 5800's support 3 Displays instead of 2. That and the low power consumption compared to high end nVidia made me buy a 5870.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only thing you need to worry about is that the graphics card you're using for gaming are connected to the monitor you're going to use. In all honesty though, it's probably best if you stick to two of the same card. I haven't tried that kind of set up before and I'm not sure how well they work, so my answer may not be the best.

Comment: I try to avoid having to buy 2 $400 cards when the second one is not used for gaming :) Otherwise I'd gladly take 2 of the same.