# Using 2 different graphics cards

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gpu, sli

I have an EVGA 9800GT on my PC and I'm running Arch Linux x64 with 2 monitors. I have a 9500GT sitting in the shelf. I found out that I could use the 9500 for physX, but I can also SLI them. Doing SLI with two different cards has a performance impact , but is this true with these cards which are almost the same?

Also please give me some notes about how to set this up on linux (either SLI or physX thing).

Comment: a little more info may be nice. What's the amount of ram on these cards, and what have you tested so far? Can you use the binary nvidia driver (which should allow SLI). PhyX seems to be supported in linux and has been since 07, but considering the state of gaming, it might be useful to dig up an application that would use it as an example.

Comment: 512MB the 9800 and 1GB the 9500. I play games on wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ChrisN Your answer is only 50% correct in its current context.

**Can I mix and match graphics cards that have different GPUs?**

AMD(CrossFire): Yes, it's called *CrossFireX Hybrid*

Nvidia(SLI): No

**"I found out that I could use the 9500 for physX.."**

True. You can mix and match Nvidia GPU's from the 8800 series and above. One will act as the Graphics processor and the other as the Physics Processor.

[Two Different nVidia Cards, One as Graphics, One as Physics - Possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/15726/two-different-nvidia-cards-one-as-graphics-one-as-physics-possible)

Note: ChrisN, if you want to incorporate these facts into your answer, I will delete this one.

Comment: actually I'm a little confused by that myself. Amount of memory definately needs to match (unless you use coolbits). I can't mix a GT with a GTS. The wording is a little unclear over the specific scenario in the question

Comment: The GPU used for graphics processing and the other for Physics processing will act as two separate entities. There is no cross communication as far as the ram and core clock is concerned. As for CrossFireX hybrid, when using two GPU's with different memory and clock speed is no different than using two different types of ddr2 RAM in dual channel mode: both sticks will simply default to that of the lesser sticks speed and capacity.

Comment: Oh phyx is straightforward. Its the wording on SLI that confuses me I don't think 8800 and 8500 count as the same series (are they?)  on the current lineup, we have three clearly different cores.

Comment: The biggest issue with this topic is that (to my memory) Nvidia purchased Physx about a year after the 8800GTX launch, and only then began integrating the technology into it's drivers. Because of Nvidia's poor marketing strategy(GPU naming conventions) it is difficult to tell which card came before the other and or what supports what. As a side note: The GT series is newer than the GTS series, so both of your cards should support what you want to do. Just stick em the box, configure 1 for physics and drive on.

Comment: ok, I'll test it...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use graphics cards with different GPUs for SLI.

> **Can I mix and match graphics cards that have different GPUs?**
>
> No. For example, an XXXGT cannot be paired with a XXXGTX in an SLI configuration.

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq#c16